# Make flexbox gap available in older versions of browsers

Tags: next.js, flexbox, emotion, mantine

I have some problem with flexbox gap (not working) in older versions of browsers and was recommended using stylis. https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylis

Im trying to figure out the documentation but I'm struggling. I guess I need to create a customized plugin? I followed some of emotion's documentation and then got stuck. Anyone who can help me?

[image: "Gap" is my supposed to be customPlugin]

My background:
Using Next.js with Mantine library (which is using emotion)

It feels like I have tried everything. I'm not so experienced so I have certainly missed something obvious.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in detail? What do you want to achieve, what are you struggling with and where are you stuck..

Comment: If I have an iphone with an old IOS version e.g and I go to my website, all my elements with "gap: value" are not working anymore. So my main goal here is to have a website working with flexbox gaps in older browsers.  

I'm stuck with creating the custom plugin (Gap-function) that will help me fix the "gap"-problem.

Comment: I had to fallback to using margin-left/right along with some odd/even rules in CSS but my layout was meant to be 2 columns so this may or may not work for your case. It will not be a perfect match but it's probably not worth overengineering it for such a small userbase (though it depends on what is typical for your site)

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Flex Gap is not supported for Safari < 14.1, and iOS Safari < 14.5 but used in mantine components (@mantine/core v5):

- Carousel: `indicators: {gap: 8}`
- Group: `root: { gap: theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }) }` -- fixed
- Stack: `root: { gap: theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }) }` -- fixed
- Tabs (TabList): `tabsList: {... if (variant === 'pills') { return { gap: theme.spacing.sm / 2, }; } ... }` -- fixed
- Calendar (CalendarBase): `calendarBase: {gap: theme.spacing.md}`

**Workaround**: Group and Stack components is a base for most Mantine components. Flex component not uses global config styles, and used for their demos, so just not use it in your codebase.

To `fix` Group and Stack components add this code to config in provider:

```
const themeConfig: MantineThemeOverride = {
  components: {
    Group: {
      styles: (theme: MantineTheme, { spacing }: GroupStylesParams) => {
        return {
          root: {
            gap: 0,
            marginRight: -theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }),
            marginBottom: -theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }),
            '> *': {
              marginRight: theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }),
              marginBottom: theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }),
            },
          },
        };
      },
    },
    Stack: {
      styles: (theme: MantineTheme, { spacing }: StackStylesParams) => {
        return {
          root: {
            gap: 0,
            marginBottom: -theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }),
            '> *': {
              marginBottom: theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }),
            },
          },
        };
      },
    },
    Tabs: {
      styles: (theme, { variant, color }: TabsStylesParams) => {
        const filledScheme = theme.fn.variant({ color, variant: 'filled' });
        let tabStyles = {};
        let tabListStyles = {};

        if (variant === 'pills') {
          const spacing = theme.spacing.sm; // In mantine is hardcoded now (https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/blob/master/src/mantine-core/src/Tabs/TabsList/TabsList.styles.ts#L46)
          tabListStyles = {
            gap: 0,
            marginRight: -spacing,
            marginBottom: -spacing,
            '> *': {
              marginRight: spacing,
              marginBottom: spacing,
            },
          };
        }

        return {
          tab: tabStyles,
          tabsList: tabListStyles,
        };
      },
    },
  },
}
```

***Known limitations***

- Must use a wrapper div when using `margin: auto` or background or when you need to make some space between container and next element. Also this may have issues in cases when some code calculates scrollHeight - it will be larger than expected by the size of gap (spacing on the bottom despite the fact that it is absorbed by the parent negative it will be calculated).
- Percentage gaps aren't reliable if the container is not full width of parent container
- Width of flex items with percentages vary slightly from spec because of negative margin on container.

***Advanced approach***: You can use modernizr config to add custom classes to the html element, so you can apply fallback values only for browsers that doesn't support flex gap.

modernizr-config.json

```
 {
  "classPrefix": "_",
  "enableClasses": true,
  "enableJSClass": true,
  "scriptGlobalName": "window",
  "usePrefixes": true,
  "minify": true,
  "options": [
    "addTest",
    "testProp",
    "setClasses"
  ],
  "feature-detects": [
    "css/flexgap",
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
 "compile-modernizr": "modernizr -c modernizr-config.json -d ./public/static/scripts/modernizr-bundle.min.js"
}
```

_document.tsx

```
<body>
  <Main />
  <NextScript />
  <Script src="/static/scripts/modernizr-bundle.min.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
</body>
```

After this, change your theme-config like this

```
    Group: {
      styles: (theme: MantineTheme, { spacing }: GroupStylesParams) => {
        return {
          root: {
            '._no-flexgap &': {
              gap: 0,
              marginRight: -theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }),
              marginBottom: -theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }),
            },
            '._no-flexgap & > *': {
              marginRight: theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }),
              marginBottom: theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }),
            },
          },
        };
      },
    },
    Stack: {
      styles: (theme: MantineTheme, { spacing }: StackStylesParams) => {
        return {
          root: {
            '._no-flexgap &': {
              gap: 0,
              marginBottom: -theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }),
            },
            '._no-flexgap & > *': {
              marginBottom: theme.fn.size({ size: spacing, sizes: theme.spacing }),
            },
          },
        };
      },
    },
```

Similar way in other cases.
So, with this optional fallback you always keep use an additional wrapper (a div) around your elements that uses gap for best backward compatibility.
I hope this helps you!

Answer (score -1):

The gap property of flexbox won't work [in older browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=flexbox%20gap) (as you just stated in your own comment). As @apokryfos suggests in the comments, you can use margins.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).